# In which cases normalize('NFKC') method work?

Tags: javascript, unicode, normalization

I tried to use `normalize('NFKC')` method with different characters, but it didn't work. Fortunately, can't say this for `NFC`. When it's possible `normalize('NFC')` always replaces multiple codepoints with the single one. For example:

```js
let t1 = `\u00F4`; //ô
let t2 = `\u006F\u0302`; //ô
console.log(t2.normalize('NFC') == t1); //true
```

And here's example with `NFKC` that never works:

```js
let s1 = '\uFB00'; //"ﬀ"
let s2 = '\u0066\u0066'; //"ff"
console.log(s2.normalize('NFKC') == s1); //false
```

I thought before that `NFKC` replaces multiple codepoints with the single one that represents compatible character. To put it simple, I thought that `NFKC` will replace `\u0066\u0066` with `\uFB00`.

If `NFKC` doesn't work like that, then... how does it work?

Comment: A ligature ﬀ is not the same as two plain "f" characters in a row.

Comment: Also note that using NFC on the same string also will not normalize to the ligature character.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, not the same. But these two symbols are compatible. That's why I thought what I thought. Then what NFKC does? Searched for information about that, didn't find something useful

Comment: No, they're not compatible. A two-f ligature does not have the same meaning as two "f" characters.

Comment: [Canonical and Compatibility Equivalence](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Canon_Compat_Equivalence) (informally interpreted): `.normalize('NFD')` is _reversible_ by `.normalize('NFC')` while `.normalize('NFKD')` is an one-way trip (like implication in logic).

Comment: @Pointy: No, no! From Unicode data: `DB00,...,<compat> 0066 0066,...`. And from the meaning of compatibility, it would be very wrong if a ligature is not compatible to the decomposing characters (and it would make compatibility just useless). -- the problem is the direction. We should never "ligate" a character (this is a task of font), but we may want to simplify things (reason of compatibility)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes, since I wrote that comment I've been reading about how decomposition/composition and "compatibility" are supposed to work, and it is very much more complicated than I had thought; in fact, now I feel like I don't understand it at all, because there are so many special cases.

Comment: @Pointy: The use cases helps: canonical -> check if strings are equivalent (or just create a canonical form). compatibility -> used for search (users may not see differences e.g. "greek letter mu" with "micro sign"). Users usually do not see ligatures, and it could have semantic value (e.g. sometime ligarures must not be performed, sometime they are just optional), or just difficult to type. (I google "3.14 m2 in sq feet" and this should give me the same result as "3.14 m²"). The original meaning changed (compatibility: was not to use but for round trip, not it is considered fully permitted).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes, it's all fascinating, but the "sometimes" parts are what makes me think it's not really possible to understand it as a fixed set of rules.

Comment: @Pointy: Forget about understanding. It is about a "natural/human" thing, so it is just impossible. Too many exceptions, special cases, old errors, etc. And different people have different opinions (also on academic level). Languages are so complex. Unicode is a representation of the "character" part, but nevertheless it is too complex to make order (it tries to describe the world, not make new synthetic rules). In fact, Unicode is not just the UnicodeData (database), but a lot of special documentation for special cases). Maps, numbers, dates, colours: every year we discover new problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is `NFKC` (as well as `NFKD`) supports compatible and canonically equivalent normalization.

[Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Description_Norm)

> The type of full decomposition chosen depends on which Unicode Normalization Form is involved. For NFC or NFD, one does a full canonical decomposition, which makes use of only canonical Decomposition_Mapping values. **For NFKC or NFKD, one does a full compatibility decomposition, which makes use of canonical and compatibility Decomposition_Mapping values.**

And that's completely understandable because as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#compatibility_normalization) says:

> All canonically equivalent sequences are also compatible, but not vice versa.

But it's also worth to notice that `NFKC` makes compatible and canonically equivalent normalizations in different ways. Canonically equivalent normalization by `NFKC` is produced the same way as `NFC`. For example:

```js
//"ô" (U+00F4) -> "a" (U+006F) + " ̂" (U+0302) -> "â" (U+00F4)
let c1 = `\u006F\u0302`; //ô
console.log(c1.normalize('NFKC').length); //1
```

But compatible normalization by this parameter works differently. The [spec](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) is saying:

> **Normalization Form KC does not attempt to map character sequences to compatibility composites.** For example, a compatibility composition of “office” does not produce “o\uFB03ce”, even though “\uFB03” is a character that is the compatibility equivalent of the sequence of three characters “ffi”. In other words, the composition phase of NFC and NFKC are the same—only their decomposition phase differs, with NFKC applying compatibility decompositions.

For example:

```js
//"ﬀ"(U+FB00) -> "f"(U+0066) + "i"(U+0066) -> "f"(U+0066) + "i"(U+0066)
let c2 = '\u0066\u0066'; //ff
console.log(c2.normalize('NFKC').length); //2
```